# connecting to remote database via opencpu javascript R libarary and rmysql library for mysql

Tags: r, rmysql, opencpu

I have a peculiar problem while trying to accessing database on remote server via opencpu javascript library for R and RMySQL library. Particularity, I have written R function that uses RMySQL library to access data from remote mysql server. And I am calling this R function from web application using opencpu java script library.

Function is able to connect (to remote mysql) and execute inside R shell on the server. But not through the opencpu library. Mysql connection settings are in ~/.my.cnf as instructed by RMySql package.

So, to tell briefly about the development environment set up

1. I have installed opencpu-server, r and my package containing function on ubuntu server 14.04 running on vmware.
2. MySql is out side vmware on host Ubuntu operating system.

Error that I am getting on the Opencpu client side

```
Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)


In call:
.local(drv, ...)
```

I am suspecting if opencpu server is not checking ~/.my.cnf for db connection settings. Any pointers to fix the problem would be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a few things:

- The `~/.my.cnf` file only works for your username. The opencpu server runs as under apache, i.e as `www-data`. It won't read configuration files from your personal home directory. Try putting it in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` or in a file under `/etc/mysql/conf.d`.
- Please check the error logs `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. There might be a security issue. Read the section 3.5 from the [opencpu PDF manual](http://jeroenooms.github.com/opencpu-manual/opencpu-server.pdf) on customizing
  the security profile.